# Javascript exec() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("input[name^=totalRent_]").each(function()
    {    var input = $(this);  
         var name = input.attr('name');  
         var num = /\d+$/.exec(name)[0];
```

My html form has:

```
    <input type="text" name="totalRent_1"  value="" /> <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="totalRent_1_hidden" /><br />
    <hr />
    <input type="text" name="totalRent_2"  value="" /> <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="totalRent_2_hidden" /><br />
    <hr />
    <input type="text" name="totalRent_3"  value="" /> <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="totalRent_3_hidden" /><br />
    <hr />
```

Now, I get a javascript error saying: 
/\d+$/.exec(name) is null

The each function is attached to ("input[name^=totalRent_]"). What do I need to do so that in's only attached to total_rent and not with totalRent_..._hidden ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select the text inputs and not the hidden ones you change your selector to filter by [multiple attributes](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeMultiple#attributeFilter1attributeFilter2attributeFilterN) (name and type):

```
$('input[name^=totalRent_][type=text]')
```

Or you can check the type attribute of the element on the *each* callback function:

```
$('input[name^=totalRent_]').each(function(){
  var input = $(this);  
  if (input.attr('type') == 'text'){
    var name = input.attr('name');  
    var num = /\d+$/.exec(name)[0];
  }
});
```

Comment: $.pimp() {function();}